# How to use task in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Sometimes  we need to a call a task in synthesizable code that is  we pass parameters to a task many of times . 
and lets us say or our call task is too long
then if we are calling task many times
so my question is that does at each time it creates instance of calling task our just pass parameters??

Comment: I think when `automatic` keyword is used in `Task` definition, it creates a new instance of calling task every time but when `automatic` is not specified, it creates only one instance and uses the same for other calls.

Comment: So  do u mean it will not generate hardware at each statement it wil just pass value to only one hardware which will be our task

Comment: I think this is so and just changes hardware input signals. Wait for expert's answer.

Comment: hey i found it in douglus n smith that it create multiple hardware whenever we call function

Answer (score 0):

> Tasks defined within a module, interface, program, or package are
>   default to being static. These items shall be shared across all uses
>   of the task executing concurrently. Tasks defined within a class are
>   always automatic.

All items declared inside automatic tasks are allocated dynamically for each invocation. All formal arguments and local variables are stored on the stack.

A task may be enabled more than once concurrently. All **variables of an automatic task** shall be **replicated on each concurrent task invocation** to store state specific to that invocation.

All **variables of a static task** shall be **static** in that there shall be a single variable corresponding to each declared local variable in a module instance, **regardless of the number of concurrent activations** of the task.

However, static tasks in different instances of a module shall have separate storage from each other.

For More information, Visit Topic 13.3 of the System Verilog LRM.

Comment: Question is on `Verilog`, not `SystemVerilog`. Main question is, does new hardware gets generated on every `task` call?

Comment: I m asking about synthesizable nature of task

Comment: whatever the nature of task i dont want to create mulitple instances of same task means i dont want replicate the hardware always u r telling at software i want to know the nature of task at hardware level

Comment: System Verilog, is an extended version of the Verilog, with OOPs concepts. But still old verilog, constructs are supported in the SV. In Hardware point of view, I believe static tasks, will generate only single hardware module. But I can't say synthesizability of the automatic tasks, but I believe, tool may give some warnings in that case